# SQL: Select value that occurs most frequently corresponding to a different column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone point me towards the right solution for my problem. 
I have a table -

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | num   | date                                 |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| a    | 1     | 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z             |
| a    | 1     | 2011-08-12T20:18:46.384Z             |
| a    | 2     | 2011-08-12T20:19:46.384Z             |
| a    | 2     | 2011-09-12T20:17:46.384Z             |
| c    | 3     | 2011-09-12T20:18:46.384Z             |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Now for a given date range, I want to fetch the most occurring value of column "num", for an "id" value.

The result for the range (2011-08-12T00:00:00.000Z to 2011-08-12T23:59:00.000Z) should be

```
| a    | 1     | 090518                               |
```

Basically, I want the most occurring value of a column corresponding to an id in a given dateTime range.

I will be using PostgreSQL.

Comment: please tag the question with the dbms being used..like Oracle,MySQL,SQL Server etc

Comment: `09052018` is not a date *range*.

Comment: what you mean by `the most occurring value`

Comment: @zohirsalak-cena For a given date range, what was the most occurring value in column "num" for an "id"

Comment: I forgot to ask,if there is  more than just one, you want to have all of them ?

Comment: No, in that case I would want one value to be chosen at random.

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI-standard formulation -- assuming `date` is stored as a date/time -- would be:

```
select num, count(*)
from t
where date >= date '2018-05-09' and
      date < date '2018-05-10'
group by num
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that most databases would have some minor variation of this syntax.  In addition, this only returns only value if there are ties.

EDIT:

The question is in the singular:

> I want to fetch the most occurring value of column "num", for an "id" value.

However, if you want all equivalent values in the case of a tie, then:

```
select num, cnt
from (select num, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where date >= date '2018-05-09' and
            date < date '2018-05-10'
      group by num
     ) n
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: and if there are 2 rows with the same count only 1 is shown. the order by clause should be desc, isn't it?

Comment: "...only value if there are ties." - Shouldn't this be if there are **no** ties?

Comment: "only returns one value" is what he meant.

Comment: This query will return two columns, num and its corresponding count. But I want something like a column "id" of unique values with the corresponding most frequent "num"

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
 select max(c.id) id, c.num, c.cnt  from 
(select id, max(cnt) cnt from (
Select id, num, count(*) cnt 
from #temp 
group by id, num)a  group by id)b 
join 
(Select id, num, count(*) cnt 
from #temp 
group by id, num)c on b.id=c.id and b.cnt=c.cnt
group by c.num, c.cnt
```

Comment: How does this accommodate the date range factor? Plus, could you please explain this a bit?

Comment: You said this is your question:  'Basically, I want the most occurring value of a column for a given id.' - Is that not what you want?

Comment: I have updated the description. I want the dateTime range to be accommodated. Missed it in the last line.

Comment: If I simply add dateTime range as a WHERE condition to the two tables that are being joined, I think this would work. Plus, what do you suggest for picking one record only in case of a tie?

Answer (score 0):

This should return something like this :

```
| id | num | occurrences |
```

---

```
select id,num,count(num) as [occurrences]
from MyTable 
where  id = 'a' /* Given id */
and [date]  >= '2011-08-12T00:00:00.000Z' AND [date]  <= '2011-08-12T23:59:00.000Z' /* Given Range */
group by id,num
order by [occurrences] DESC
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the column "id" in the result to have unique values with the most occurring "num" value. How do I modify the above query to give me the desired result?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by ` the column "id" in the result to have unique values with the most occurring "num" value`, the id column here is redundant since you're providing it as a condition.

Comment: I won't be providing the "id" as an input. For a given dateTime range, I would like to get a result which would have a column "id" with unique values and a column "num" with the most frequently occurring value. If for a dateRange there are 5 entries for id "a" with column num value as 1 1 1 2 3,  I would want my result to have one entry for id "a" with value "1" in the column num. Does this clear things up?

Comment: I think your best bet is to use a cursor.